# fill word document from Access form in runtime mode

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime

I will describe my problem as points:

1. I have an Access database with functions & macros
2. there is a function to fill data into Word document (it works well)
3. I am using late binding
4. the database should be available to users who don't have Microsoft Application so I install Access runtime (it works well except the function of Word didn't work)
5. the code below works on a machine that has Access Application but doesn't on other machines.

How can I get the code to run in the Access Runtime?

```
Private Sub Command96_Click()
Dim appWord As Object
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Dim doc As Object

'Set doc = CreateDocument("Word.Document")
'Avoid error 429, when Word isn't open.

On Error Resume Next

Err.Clear

'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.

Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.

'Set appWord = New Word.Application
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If

'Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("\\ubcdatacenter\Public\UBCIEDatabase\DOC\H_F.docx", , True)
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("\\ubcdatacenter\Public\UBCIEDatabase\DOC\H_F.docx")
With doc

.FormFields("BookID").Result = Me!ID
.FormFields("Book_BC_date").Result = Me!date_BC
.FormFields("Book_AH_date").Result = Me!date_AH
.FormFields("Book_AH_date").Result = Me!date_AH
.FormFields("BookTopic").Result = Me!topic
.FormFields("BookProjectName").Result = Me!projectName
.FormFields("BookCompanyName").Result = Me!companyName
.FormFields("BookContent").Range.Text = Me!content

.Visible = True

.Activate

End With

Set doc = Nothing

Set appWord = Nothing

Exit Sub

errHandler:

MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: You write: "users who don't have Microsoft Application". Does this mean they have NO Microsoft applications installed, or just Access isn't installed? If WORD is not installed, the code cannot run.

Comment: Please turn error handling back on (`On Error GoTo 0`) after `End If`. Then test again in the runtime and tell us what error(s) are being displayed. (Note: the `errHandler` in the code does nothing, since there is no `On Error GoTo errHandler` in the code.)

Comment: ohhh, thanks so much, you are right, I tried on devices that don't have all office application, when I test on device has just Word it work!